# How to respond with new httpstatus code in Spring mvc

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I'm using spring MVC for creation Rest Web service. and would like to send a 213 code status as response. but this code doesn't exist in the class org.springframework.http.HttpStatus and the class ResponseEntity(T body, HttpStatus statusCode) accept HttpStatus type. 
How we deal to send this httpStatus code?
 here is pseudo code:

```
 public ResponseEntity<?> getEvents() {
   //1. call Service 1
   // 2. use result of service 1 to call service 2

   // 3. use result of service 2 to call service 3

   // 4. create result and map it in DTO object

   if( result of service 1 is empty) return empty result with status 213
   if( result of service 2 is empty) return empty result with status 214

    return new ResponseEntity(result.getBody(), status code) ;;
}
```

Comment: Can you post some sample of code, to show what you're trying to do? There are many different ways to return something from a controller in Spring. So sample code will help me answer to your code style better.

Comment: What are you attempting to accomplish by using a non-standard HTTP status code? Codes in the 200s generally indicate a successful request processing. Is there some sort of edge success case that you are attempting to indicate/handle?

Comment: Very valid question. It would be very useful for implementing REST API. Was anybody able to workaround this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a rather hacky but still quite simple and easy workaround:

```
new ResponseEntity<String>(
    "my body", 
    null, 
    HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT /*status doesn't matter, just has to be anything*/
) {
    @Override
    public int getStatusCodeValue() {
        return MY_CUSTOM_RESPONSE_CODE;
    }
};
```